How can i get the audio metadata (duration) using library react-native-sound-player before start?
I can't get the audio metadata, more specifically the audio duration before start.
I'm using react-native-sound-player library of React Native CLI.
This is because i have mutiples audios in a chat conversation and i need the duration information before it is started so i can use it on the player component when it is built.
Its seems that this library only get this information after started.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';
import Icon from '../components/Icon/Icon';
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const propTypes = {
audioUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
mainColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const CustomAudioPlayer = ({ audioUrl, mainColor }) =\> {
const \[isPlaying, setIsPlaying\] = useState(false);
const \[elapsedTime, setElapsedTime\] = useState(0);
const \[duration, setDuration\] = useState(0);
const currentAudioUrl = useRef("");

useEffect(() => {
    SoundPlayer.setVolume(1);
    retrieveCurrentAudioUrl();
}, []);

const retrieveCurrentAudioUrl = async () => {
    try {
        const url = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentAudioUrl');
        if (url !== null) {
            currentAudioUrl.current = url;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao recuperar a URL do áudio:', error);
    }
};

const saveCurrentAudioUrl = async (url) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('currentAudioUrl', url);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao salvar a URL do áudio:', error);
    }
};

const togglePlay = async () => {
    try {
        if (currentAudioUrl.current === audioUrl) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                await SoundPlayer.pause(); 
                setIsPlaying(false);
            } else {
                await SoundPlayer.resume();
                setIsPlaying(true);
            }
        } else {
            await SoundPlayer.stop();
            await SoundPlayer.seek(0); 
            setElapsedTime(0);
            await saveCurrentAudioUrl(audioUrl);
            
            await SoundPlayer.playUrl(audioUrl);
            const info = await SoundPlayer.getInfo();
            setDuration(info.duration); 
            setIsPlaying(true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao reproduzir/pausar o áudio:', error);
    }
};

const formatTime = (seconds) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    const formattedTime = `${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(remainingSeconds).padStart(2, '0')}`;
    return formattedTime;
};



useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;
    if (isPlaying) {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setElapsedTime((prevElapsedTime) => {
                if (prevElapsedTime >= Math.round(duration)) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    setIsPlaying(false);
                    setElapsedTime(0);
                    return 0;
                }
                return prevElapsedTime + 1;
            });
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, [isPlaying, duration]);

return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Pressable onPress={togglePlay}>
            <Icon icon={isPlaying ? 'pause-outline' : 'play-outline'} color={mainColor} size={24} />
        </Pressable>
        <Text style={{color: mainColor}}>  {formatTime(elapsedTime)} / {formatTime(Math.round(duration))}</Text>
    </View>
);

};

CustomAudioPlayer.propTypes = propTypes;
export default CustomAudioPlayer;

´´´
